# jquery addclass if some number of li's haveclass

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, addclass

I am attempting to add a class to a span, if a set of li's have a specific class applied to them.

li . complete

li

li . complete

li

li . complete

etc...

span # done

I was attempting to add a class of "active"  to the span if 4 of the li's have the class "complete"
I've tried the following, and I can get the click event to work but not the if statement, and is this even possible or efficiient?

```
$(function(){
$("li").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass("complete");
});
if($("li").hasClass("complete")){
   $("#done").addClass("active");
};
});
```

Ive been digging for a way to maybe count the li.complete's withing the dom then addClass against it but haven't had much luck

Thanks

Comment: im not sure what that whole top part of your question is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code won't has two problems: you're running

```
if($("li").hasClass("complete")){
   $("#done").addClass("active");
};
```

immediately after binding the `click()` handler, not after the button has actually been clicked. Additionally, you're not counting the number of `li`s that have been made complete.

One option is this, counting the number of `li`'s with the class complete each time you handle the click:

```
$(function(){
$("li").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass("complete");

   if ($("li.complete").length >= 4) {
       $("#done").addClass("active");
   }
});
});
```

You could also keep a running count as you go...

```
$(function(){
var activeCount = 0;
$("li").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass("complete");

   activeCount = activeCount + 1;

   if (activeCount >= 4) {
       $("#done").addClass("active");
   }
});
});
```

but if you ever want to be able to unselect items, this would make your code more complicated.

Comment: That's perfect, Thank you so much for your help and explaining the error in my ways, LOL. as I am working on learning JavaScript every bit helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("li").click(function(){
         $(this).addClass("complete");
            if($("li.complete").length >= 4){
                 $("#done").addClass("active");
            };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, and you want to apply a class to an element if 4 `li` elements all have a specific class, you can do this:

```
if($("li.complete").length == 4) {
    $("#done").addClass("active");
}
```

See an example of it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/nmue5/).

Answer (score 0):

You could count all of the `li` elements that have your complete selector and see if the count is at least 4:

```
if($("li.complete").size() > 3) {
   $("#done").addClass("active");
}
```